# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Linq to SQL object stored in session

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a multi-page (multi-view) form in MVC, the results of which will be saved to a single database table.

Code snippet that initializes the linq object in the first page of the form.

```
public ActionResult MyForm()
{
    // returns a Linq object stored in session
    Application currentApp = Application.FromSession(); 

    // if null, initialize the object and save to session
    if (currentApp == null)
    {
        currentApp = new Application();
        currentApp.SessionSave();
    }
    return View(currentApp);
}
```

And here is a sample snippet of code for the final action that updates some data from the strongly-typed model, then triggers the database save.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyForm3(Application app, FormCollection coll)
{
    Application currentApp = Application.FromSession();
    currentApp.Contact = app.Contact;
    currentApp.AddFormToXml(coll);
    currentApp.SessionSave();

    _db.Applications.InsertOnSubmit(currentApp);
    _db.SubmitChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Blah");
}
```

**The problem** I'm running into is that the SubmitChanges fails with the error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'ApplicationData', table
>   'MyTable';
>   column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails. The statement has been
>   terminated.

In this case, ApplicationData is a column of type xml, which LINQ interprets as an XElement object.  When I set a breakpoint at SubmitChanges() and check the value of app.ApplicationData, it is clearly populated (non-null), and yet I continue to get this error.  My only thought is that I am misunderstanding something with how data contexts work.  It only seems to have an issue with this one column though.  Is it possible that I need to figure out a way to attach the XElement object (ApplicationData) to my active data context (_db), and if so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Your code implies you're trying to insert currentApp but your comment says you checked column value in app. The references are to different objects. What am I missing?

Comment: currentApp is loaded from Session, as it has the partial updates to the Linq object.  The reason I can't simply save/reload from DB each time is that there are required fields spread throughout the multiple pages of this form, which is why I'm keeping it in Session.  When a page is posted, I update the session instance with just those values that came from that particular page.  I do not save to DB until the final page is posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the actual SQL generated and sent to the server.

Start up SQL Server Profiler (on the tools menu in SQL Server Management Studio) and start a trace. Run your application until it crashes. Go back to SQL profiler and look at the SQL queries. Seeing things from the SQL end sometimes make it easy to spot the error, e.g. finding out if your are doing several inserts instead of just one.

Comment: Due to the fact that storing object in Session requires serialization, its no wonder I was having difficulties.  I ended up changing the code to load/reload the DB record during each request and changed all of the fields to Nullable so I could partially update the record without SQL errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well my suggestion to you is to compare the data type of "ApplicationData" column in your Context model and in your database table.

Also please check your LINQ to SQL mappings for this column "AppliationData" again on the datatype itself.

Please update your post if you find anything...

Comment: ApplicationData in the dbml is shown as type System.Xml.Linq.XElement, as expected.  The server data type is "Xml NOT NULL", as expected.

Comment: what is the datatype of this column in your DB table?

Comment: can you post the property mappings of the object (that is using the ApplicationData column) ? that will give me something to work with...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so in the action method you mentioned can you check if you are calling the InsertOnSumbit Method again anywhere else before you are finally calling db.SubmitChanges()...or if you are calling the InsertOnSubmit method more than once... I think that will cause a problem if you are calling it twice on the same object.

**Update:**
I did tried a sample with a single table and was able to insert the xml data as mentioned below.

```
    DataClassesDataContext ctx = new DataClassesDataContext();
    Application a1 = new Application();
    XName n = "dfdsf";
    a1.ApplicationData = new XElement(n);
    ctx.Applications.InsertOnSubmit(a1);
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

so, now the question will be what does your column data looks like??? if you can post the sample content of the application data then it will be helpful. Also how are you setting the ApplicationData property value?